# How to install clrzmq using Package Manager Console for a console c# application?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, zeromq, package-managers

**Scenario:** Once Node.js server has ZeroMQ pull listening on `tcp://127.0.0.1:2202`. And the data had to be sent by C# Console Application.

**Issue:**
[Example Reference](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq#example-client)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using ZMQ;

namespace ZMQGuide
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ZMQ Context and client socket
            using (ZmqContext context = ZmqContext.Create())
            using (ZmqSocket client = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.PUSH))
            {
                client.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:2202");

                string request = "Hello";
                for (int requestNum = 0; requestNum < 10; requestNum++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sending request {0}...", requestNum);
                    client.Send(request, Encoding.Unicode);

                    string reply = client.Receive(Encoding.Unicode);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received reply {0}: {1}", requestNum, reply);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is gives following error:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'ZmqContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    D:\..\Program.cs    26  24  PROJECTA
```

**Information:** I tried to install latest version using Package Manager Console, by issuing command `PM> Install-Package clrzmq`
Output after command:

```
'clrzmq 2.2.5' already installed.
Successfully added 'clrzmq 2.2.5' to PROJECTA.
```

**Question:** Can anyone tell me, where I am going wrong or what am I missing?

---

**Update:** I had [downloaded](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq/downloads) and tried, but no luck :-)

Advance Thanks for great help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue. I think it's perhaps because the documentation is a bit out of date but this seems to build for me:

```
using ZMQ;

namespace TestConsole 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ZMQ Context and client socket
            using (Context context = new Context())
            using (Socket client = context.Socket(SocketType.PUSH))
            {
                client.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:2202");

                string request = "Hello";
                for (int requestNum = 0; requestNum < 10; requestNum++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sending request {0}...", requestNum);
                    client.Send(request, Encoding.Unicode);

                    string reply = client.Recv(Encoding.Unicode);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received reply {0}: {1}", requestNum, reply);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have ZeroMQ or anything running to actually check that it works, but perhaps you could give it a shot?

Comment: No luck :-(   `Error 1 The type or namespace name 'ZeroMQ' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\..\Program.cs 6 7 ProjectA`

Comment: Sorry about that...I just dragged the package down from NuGet and tried to get things running. Have updated my answer with what worked for me (at least to the getting it to build stage)

Comment: Thanks for the great help.. I landed with this but for me now the issues is at server side (code above is of client). Getting exception when first message gets received.. `Unhandled Exception: ZMQ.Exception: Not supported at ZMQ.Socket.Send(Byte[] message, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, SendRecvOpt[] flags)`

Comment: Glad you got it working...Sorry, I'm no ZMQ expert so I wish I could help more, but regret that I can't :-(

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, to get the latest version (3.0) of clrzmq (ZeroMQ) I needed to add the "-Version" option to the Package Manager call like this:

PM> `Install-Package clrzmq -Version 3.0.0-rc1`

Also, when using 3.0 the "using" is ZeroMQ instead of ZMQ:

`using ZeroMQ;`